# Unable to deploy code on ec2 instance using codedeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have single ec2 instance running on ubuntu server and I am trying to implement CI/CD flow using codedeploy and source is bit-bucket.I jave also installed codedeploy-agent on ec2 instance and it is installed and running successfully but whenever I am deploying code on ec2 deployment is failing with an error shown below:

```
The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few 
healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are 
experiencing problems.
```

In the CodeDeploy agent log file that I am accessing using `less /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log` showing below error:

```
ERROR [codedeploy-agent(31598)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: 
Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile
```

I am unable to understand how can I overcome this error someone let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeDeploy agent requires IAM permissions provided by IAM role/profile of your instance. The exact permissions needed are given in AWS docs:

- [Step 4: Create an IAM instance profile for your Amazon EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html)

Comment: I have created IAM role for my ec2 instance but now error shows `The CodeDeploy agent did not find an AppSpec file within the unpacked revision directory at revision-relative path "appspec.yml".`

Comment: How can I create this appspec.yml file and what should I include in it.

Comment: @Digvijay This is the new issue, thus I would suggest making the new question with relevant details.

Comment: Could you please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813464/showing-error-in-creating-bitbucket-pipeline-for-aws-codedeploy-on-ec2