# Showing error in creating bitbucket pipeline for aws codedeploy on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I am trying to create bitbucket pipeline for performing an EC2 deployment using AWS CodeDeploy but it is showing warning at the time of creation which is:

```
Expected a section but found sequence.
```

What is this warning about even if I am doing exactly the same way given in documentation.

Below is screenshot:

[image]

Someone let me know how can I correct it.

Comment: This is not about `appspec.yml` as you noted earlier?

Comment: Yeah i know that actually I am trying bitbucket way of deployment on ec2 instance .

Comment: I see. Sadly I'm not too familiar with bitbucket, thus can't help much. Sorry.

Comment: No issue friend so could u plz tell me about how can I create appspec.yml will create a new post and will share u the link.

Comment: Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813632/code-deploy-agent-unable-to-find-appspec-yml-file if u could help me out.