# Code deploy agent unable to find appspec.yml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to perform CI/CD workflow on ec2 instance using aws codedeploy but I am getting below error at the time of deployment:

```
The CodeDeploy agent did not find an AppSpec file within the unpacked revision directory at 
revision-relative path "appspec.yml".
```

How can I create `appsepc.yml` file in order to succeed deployment.As I doing it first time.Someone let me know.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how you can create your file?

Comment: I have created it and code has been depoyed successfully on ec2 instance but app is crashing plz go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819491/node-js-app-is-crashing-on-aws-ec2-instance

Comment: Sure. But if any of the answers was helpful for the current question, it's acceptance is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact setup of [appsepc.yml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html#appspec-reference-server) is use-case specific, and it has to be tailored to your application requirements. Thus you are the only one who can create it.

But AWS provides examples of such files:

- [AppSpec File example for an EC2/On-Premises deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html#appspec-file-example-server)
- [aws-codedeploy-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codedeploy-samples/tree/master/applications)

Answer (score 1):

appspec.yml file is what instructs the codedeploy agent on what are the steps to run on the EC2 instances. You can find the detailed structure and example provided by [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html#appspec-reference-server)